# Is it OK to use Java Records with @Service / @RestController annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'd prefer it as a record as there is less boilerplate, but would there be issues?

IntelliJ is suggesting that I turn a basic Java class @Service like this:

```
@Service
public class LocationService {
    private final PlaceRepository placeRepository;

    @Autowired
    public LocationService(PlaceRepository placeRepository) {
        this.placeRepository = placeRepository;
    }

    public List<PlaceDto> findPlacesByRegionId(Long regionId){
        return placeRepository.findByRegionId(regionId).stream().map(place -> new PlaceDto(place.getId(), place.getName())).toList();
    }
}
```

into a Java record @Service like this:

```
@Service
public record LocationService(PlaceRepository placeRepository) {
    public List<PlaceDto> findPlacesByRegionId(Long regionId) {
        return placeRepository.findByRegionId(regionId).stream().map(place -> new PlaceDto(place.getId(), place.getName())).toList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it, and if so did it work? Then you answered your own question.

Comment: I did and it does, however I'm not sure whether it's a normal thing to do. It's not very conventional.

Comment: Records are just a type of class, so what a class can do, a record can too. I'm not sure I would do this (but that is my opinion), because you will be exposing `PlaceRepository` as a property, which the original solution did not, and formally, records are intended as data carriers, and a service isn't really a data carrier. However, technically, you should be just fine.

Comment: Seems your `@Service` is not defined as valid Spring's way. `PlaceRepository placeRepository` should be @Autowired itself, not by `LocationService` constructor

Comment: @Valijon pretty sure Autowiring by constructor is preferred to Autowiring a field itself

Comment: Different authors strongly prefer different models of wiring up injected components. This wouldn't matter too much except some people seem to insist that the way they do it is The Only True Way, which is quite clearly not actually the case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could do that, but records have getters (well without `get` prefix). Which Service Layer shouldn't have. Your Service Facade exposes public methods which also are usually `@Transactional`, you don't want to mix them with methods that no one is going to use.

Also, records define `equals()` & `hashCode()` which aren't needed for Service classes either.

In the end the only common theme between Records and Services is that all fields are usually `final` and all of them are usually passed via constructor. This isn't much of commonality. So it sounds like a bad idea to use records for this.

Answer (score 13):

Let me quote [Oracle guy](https://nipafx.dev/java-record-semantics/):

> JEP 395 says:
>
> > [Records] are classes that act as transparent carriers for immutable
> > data.
>
> So by creating a record you're telling the compiler, your colleagues,
> the whole wide world that this type is about data. More precisely,
> data that's (shallowly) immutable and transparently accessible. That's
> the core semantic - everything else follows from here.
>
> If this semantic doesn't apply to the type you want to create, then
> you shouldn't create a record. If you do it anyways (maybe lured in by
> the promise of no boilerplate or because you think records are
> equivalent to @Data/@Value or data classes), you're muddying your
> design and chances are good that it will come back to bite you. So
> don't.

UPD.

I have spent a couple of minutes to figure out what was the root cause of your statement that "IntelliJ is suggesting that I turn a basic Java class @Service like this". And have found the following discussion: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252036

Thereby:

- using records for spring beans is definitely a bad idea: such beans are not eligible for auto proxying, moreover records are not designed for such scenarios
- it is embarrassing but JetBrains does mislead CE users

Comment: To add to this, I'm using Ultimate edition 2021.3.